# Is there any function for UTC to convert to particular datetime to UTC date time

Tags: c#

I want to convert for example a particular date 12-11-2008 11:33:04.510 to UTC datetime. Can anyone help me how to do this. I want to do this in c# coding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx), assuming it's in the local timezone of your computer at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

DateTime is not timezone-aware. It can be treated as local time or UTC time, and as Jon Skeet said, DateTime.ToUniversalTime can convert between them.

In .NET3.5 there is also the TimeZoneInfo class which allows for conversion of DateTime's between arbitrary timezones, but for your needs, the former is probably good enough.
There's also a DateTimeOffset class which works just like a DateTime, except it also stores an offset from UTC, making it a bit more robust if you have to handle multiple timezones.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DateTime to be identified as a UTC, you can also assign it a DateTimeKind,

DateTime saveNow = DateTime.Now;
DateTime myDt;
 myDt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(saveNow, DateTimeKind.Utc);

Or if you know it's local:
string formattedDate = "12-11-2008 11:33:04.510";
  DateTime localDt = DateTime.Parse(formattedDate, null, 
                                              DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal);

Or if you know it's UTC:
string formattedDate = "12-11-2008 11:33:04.510";
  DateTime localDt = DateTime.Parse(formattedDate, null, 
                                              DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);